# How to show an expression like $a=max(b,c)$ is true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need to show that:

$$\frac{1-\delta^{s-1}} {1-\delta} = \max \left\{ \delta \frac{1-\delta^{s-1}}{1-\delta}, 1+\delta \frac{1-\delta^{s-2}}{1-\delta} \right\}, \forall s\ge 2 $$, where $s \in \mathbb{Z}_+, \delta\in (0,1)$

How do I do this? So far, all the questions I have encountered are of the kind $a=b$ i.e. no max/min on the right hand side so all I needed to do was to show $a-b=0$. But in this case, the presence of max at the right hand side has me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that:

$$1+\delta \frac{1-\delta^{s-2}}{1-\delta}=\frac{1-\delta}{1-\delta}+\frac{\delta-\delta^{s-1}}{1-\delta}=\frac{1-\delta^{s-1}}{1-\delta}$$

So you have expression like $a=\max(b,a)$, not $a=\max(b,c)$. Next you have to show that:

$$\frac{1-\delta^{s-1}}{1-\delta} \geq \delta\frac{1-\delta^{s-1}}{1-\delta}$$

But it is obvious, because $\frac{1-\delta^{s-1}}{1-\delta} > 0$ and $\delta<1$.